# Blender 2.71 parenting objects transforms objects

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

Whenever I parent an object it gets distorted or transformed in some form or fashion when I press "P" in game mode...is there a way to fix this?

See the top picture shows what it supposed to look like...then I press "P" in game mode and we jump to the picture below and objects go megatron on me and are transformed.

[image: **what it supposed to look like**]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A general advice is to have no scale on your objects if you do not need it. One thing you really need to avoid is in-homogeneous scaling (the axis get different scales).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the scale of the parent objects into the mesh via <kbd>ctr+a</kbd> + Scale

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Lol...already got a work around and ditched the parenting all together but will have to keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the scaling does not change when entering the game engine. This is different, when you are playing an animation or change something via Python.

My advice to you is to void scaling (especially the in-homogeneousscaling) at the parents.

If you need scaled meshes, you can create the object tree by using empties as parent. You can parent the previous parent objects to the empties. This way they are no parents anymore and you can scale them without side effects. Just make sure the empties are not scaled.

Example:

```
Frame (scaled)
- Button A (scaled)
- Button B (scaled)
```

changed to:

```
Root (Unscaled Empty)
- Frame (scaled)
- Button A (scaled)
- Button B (scaled)
```

or

```
Root (Unscaled Empty)
- Frame (scaled)
- Button Base (Unscaled Empty)
  - Button A (scaled)
  - Button B (scaled)
```

Comment: I don't want anything scaled though.

All I want is for the mesh to stay the same as shown in image 1 (top) but once I parent an object(s) to another object and press "P" in game mode it transforms the object as shown in image 2 (bottom).

I have no type of scaling animation or coding in the file nor do I want anything to be scaled.

Comment: In that case I suggest to apply the scale of the objects into the mesh via <ctr+a> + Scale.

Comment: added the file so you can probably see what I'm talking about...all you need to do is press "p" in game mode

Comment: I do not see any unwanted scales. In my version (2.74) the preview matches the in-game look. I tested in 2.76 - it does not apply unwanted scale either.

Comment: I see in your file the objects are not parented together. Is that a solution?

Comment: I went ahead and did a work around and removed the parents and it stopped the scaling in the preview.

But if I were to parent the object(s) and then do preview, they'll get transformed in some way

Comment: As said: unsure there is no scaling at the parents, either by converting them into mesh scale or by using other un-scaled parents. Both solutions worked on your file.